# Augustyniak/RATreeView Scroll UI issue that has persisted for a while

Tags: ios, swift, treeview

Have a scroll UI issue when I use the dynamically calculated height of [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) cells.
Initial RATreeView control setup

```
func setupTreeView() {
    treeView = RATreeView(frame: view.bounds)
    treeView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: EquipmentListCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: EquipmentListCell.self))
    treeView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: EquipmentChildCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: EquipmentChildCell.self))
    treeView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: EquipmentCollectionCellDetail.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: EquipmentCollectionCellDetail.self))
    treeView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: EquipmentLevelCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: EquipmentLevelCell.self))

    treeView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    treeView.delegate = self
    treeView.dataSource = self
    treeView.treeFooterView = UIView()
    treeView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

    treeView.backgroundView = loadingView
    view.addSubview(treeView)
}
```

For example, if I use just this everything is fine

```
func treeView(_ treeView: RATreeView, heightForRowForItem item: Any) -> CGFloat {
     return 50
}
```

But, I make different heights for the treeView and under the particular conditions - just hide the cells by setup height = 0.
 Here, I get a scroll [issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UN7mkLgqumzbxNrFq9QrdKkP09MML9Hp/view?usp=sharing)

```
func treeView(_ treeView: RATreeView, heightForRowForItem item: Any) -> CGFloat {
    return stats.total.toInt() == 0 ? 0 : 50
}
```

Here is opened GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView/issues/250) also,

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Explain your question and issue, this is very little information

Comment: @MilanNosáľ tried to add more details, hope it's clear. Thanks for noticing!